# Is it possible to find the manufacturer of a BLE device from it's mac address?

Tags: hardware, mac-address, bluetooth

Tools like nmap are able to identify the make of a device based on it's mac address. Is there a tool or a reference to identify the make of a Bluetooth Low Energy device based on its mac address?

Comment: When you say hardware address you meant mac address I presume?

Comment: @LesterT. Yes, Mac address!

Comment: many 802 devices allow custom MAC setting, not sure about bt, but it's possible in theory...

Answer (score 3):

You can refer to this [Wikipedia writeup](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address?wprov=sfla1)

And yes, Hardware Manufacturer can be identified from the first 3 octet aka OUI
[image: Hardware Manufacturer can be identified from the first 3 octet aka OUI]

Sources: Wikipedia

**What is an OUI then?**

An OUI {Organizationally Unique Identifier} consists of a 24-bit number that uniquely identifies a vendor or manufacturer. The 24-bit numbers are purchased and assigned by the IEEE.

If you want to jump straight to searching for Manufacturers based on brands. you could google it. Here are some of the links.

[1. Macvendors.com](https://macvendors.com/)

[2. macvendorlookup.com](http://www.macvendorlookup.com/)

[3. coffer.com/mac_find/](http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/)

[4. Wireshark OUI lookup](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/oui-lookup.html)

[5. macvendors.co](https://macvendors.co/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There's a very well maintained MAC vendor list [here](https://macvendors.com).

Just enter the address and it will find you the vendor. The 1st 3 octets are the vendor-specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I understand the other answers here. Those answers and links are for Ethernet MAC addresses, not Bluetooth -- so they do not answer the question appropriately.

For a list of BDADDR MAC addresses, see this database -- http://web.archive.org/web/20100604064309/http://802.15ninja.net/bnapbnap/thelist.php

You can also find out which Bluetooth devices are around you by using the BTScanner (actively) or bluelog (passively, over time) tools.

I also recommend under Linux that you check out the `hcitool scan --all --flush` and `bluetoothctl` commands since they offer active and passive Bluetooth device identification capabilities as well.

Comment: Comparing the list you've supplied with the one in the other posts by checking a few random vendors, I can't find any differences. Do you have any information about the differences between MAC of ethernet devices and MAC of bluetooth devices?

Comment: Can't find any difference other than that the list I gave has WAY more information?

Comment: http://www.willhackforsushi.com/presentations/icanhearyounow-sansns2007.pdf

Comment: @aldre +1 for the presentation, very useful.